# Make table images database images from JSON urls

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reference

I am trying to make table images the specific person's profile image that is stored in my firebase. I have a NSURL that can print the list of urls but I don't know how to add it to the UIImage for each person in their own cell. I have the code here:

```
      import UIKit
      import Firebase

   class NetworkTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var data = [String]()

var users = [User]()

let cellId = "cellId"

var filteredData: [String]!

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self

    fetchUsers()

    filteredData = data

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return filteredData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId)! as UITableViewCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = user.name

    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Placeholder Photo")

    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
        let url = NSURL(string: profileImageUrl)

        }

    return cell
}

//Mark: Search Bar Config
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filteredData = []


    if searchText == "" {
        filteredData = data

    }
    else {
        for fruit in data {

            if fruit.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {

                filteredData.append(fruit)
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func fetchUsers() {

    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {

            let user = User()


            user.name = dictionary["name"]
            user.email = dictionary["email"]
            user.facebookUrl = dictionary["facebookUrl"]
            user.instagramUrl = dictionary["instagramUrl"]
            user.linkedInUrl = dictionary["linkedInUrl"]
            user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"]
            user.twitterUrl = dictionary["twitterUrl"]

           // print(user.name!)

            self.users.append(user)
            self.data.append(user.name!)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
   }
}
```

The tutorial I've been watching is out of date and I don't know what I should be putting here to assign the images to the correct table cells.

Comment: The approach is going to be problematic. Can you imagine, as a user, scrolling through a tableView as it stutters and stops while it awaits hundreds of images to download while it's scrolling? ugh. A better approach is to store the images (thumbnails) in the tableView dataSource `users` so when populating the cells, get the text like you are `cell.textLabel?.text = user.name` and the the image `cell.imageView?.image = user.image`. It's fast and if a cell needs to be re-created, it doesn't have to re-download data that was already downloaded.

Comment: Oh - you as a side note. In your search bar, you don't need a separate array `self.data` for the users name, as it's already stored in the dataSource `self.users`. Navigating two arrays can get complex when sorting, selecting etc.

Comment: I can't get the users array to call the names so I had to append the data with just the users' names. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: It's actually pretty straightforward with Swift but I don't know what you're `User` class looks like. Also, that answer would be unrelated to the question so it would be a bit off topic. Do a seach on swift filtering an array of objects and you'll get dozens of solutions. If not, post a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). It's very easy to use.

Simply add the URL to the image view

```
let url = URL(string: "") // enter your URL string here
self.imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

And don't forget to also update your UI from the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```